# Neo4j Cypher query about finding like minded people

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know this may be a simple question but I'm having a hard time finding an answer.

I want to find all "Persons" who have `INTERESTED_IN` the same `Activities` as a Person with the id of 1 that is not `FRIENDS_WITH` person 1

Something like

```
MATCH (p:Person {Id:1})--[r:INTERSTED_IN]-->(a:Activity {name:Skiing})<--(f:Person)
RETURN f.name
```

Might be wrong..

I think this will find everyone with the same relationship but then I want to make sure they aren't already friends.

Trying to figure out cypher and can't find any good examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost got it!

```
MATCH (p:Person { id: 1 })-[r:INTERESTED_IN]->(a:Activity { name: 'Skiing' })<-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]-(f:Person)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(f)
RETURN f.name
```

Note that `id` here is a property, and not the internal node ID. If that's what you're looking for, you'd do this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:INTERESTED_IN]->(a:Activity { name: 'Skiing' })<-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]-(f:Person) 
WHERE ID(p) = 1 AND NOT (p)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(f)
RETURN f.name
```

And it's "cypher." ;-)

Comment: You know, you can suggest edits to the question to fix typos and used tags. See my edit. When you do this the next time, provide a good edit description which says why you're doing this. Mine is a bit lazy.